# How to build an iframe page that searches and displays multiple sites?

Tags: javascript, search, iframe

I'm trying to build a page similar to www.bing-vs-google.com, but instead of bing and google, I want to populate it with several of my company's internally-used sites.  This would function as a "universal search" for our employees to search across a variety of sites (all of which pass search queries via URL).

Has anyone seen or done this before?  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Simply include two iframes:

```
<iframe src="http://www.bing.com/search?q=foo"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-a&q=foo"></iframe>
```

Where you replace `foo` with the search string and the domains with your internal search engines. You shouldn't expect neither `google` nor `bing` indexing your intranet pages so you need your own indexing engine.

Comment: This will not work due to `X-Frame-Options` header. Use this URL for Google: https://www.google.com/search?igu=1&q=foo